# eps ai to png adobe illustrator js script, how to make it look in sub folders?

Tags: script, javascript, adobe-illustrator

I found this script online which allows you to batch convert .ai or .eps to png however it only works on one folder at a time, could someone help/tell me what to adjust to make it work on subfolders? someone mentioned using the resurse command?

source:http://forums.adobe.com/message/4915414#4915414

```
/**********************************************************
```

ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED 
Copyright 2005 Adobe Systems Incorporated 
All Rights Reserved

NOTICE:  Adobe permits you to use, modify, and 
distribute this file in accordance with the terms
of the Adobe license agreement accompanying it.
If you have received this file from a source 
other than Adobe, then your use, modification,
or distribution of it requires the prior 
written permission of Adobe.

*********************************************************/

/**********************************************************

Save as PDFs.js

DESCRIPTION

This sample gets files specified by the user from the 
selected folder and batch processes them and saves them 
as PDFs in the user desired destination with the same 
file name.

**********************************************************/

// Main Code [Execution of script begins here]

// uncomment to suppress Illustrator warning dialogs
// app.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevel.DONTDISPLAYALERTS;

var destFolder, sourceFolder, files, fileType, sourceDoc, targetFile, pngExportOpts;

// Select the source folder.
sourceFolder = Folder.selectDialog( 'Select the folder with Illustrator files you want to convert to PNG', '~' );

// If a valid folder is selected
if ( sourceFolder != null )
{
    files = new Array();
    fileType = prompt( 'Select type of Illustrator files to you want to process. Eg: *.ai', ' ' );

```
// Get all files matching the pattern
files = sourceFolder.getFiles( fileType );

if ( files.length > 0 )
{
    // Get the destination to save the files
    destFolder = Folder.selectDialog( 'Select the folder where you want to save the converted PNG files.', '~' );
    for ( i = 0; i < files.length; i++ )
    {
        sourceDoc = app.open(files[i]); // returns the document object

        // Call function getNewName to get the name and file to save the pdf
        targetFile = getNewName();

        // Call function getPNGOptions get the PNGExportOptions for the files
        pngExportOpts = getPNGOptions();

        // Export as PNG
        sourceDoc.exportFile( targetFile, ExportType.PNG24, pngExportOpts );

        sourceDoc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
    }
    alert( 'Files are saved as PNG in ' + destFolder );
}
else
{
    alert( 'No matching files found' );
}
```

}

/*********************************************************

getNewName: Function to get the new file name. The primary
name is the same as the source file.

**********************************************************/

function getNewName()
{
    var ext, docName, newName, saveInFile, docName;
    docName = sourceDoc.name;
    ext = '.png'; // new extension for png file
    newName = "";

```
for ( var i = 0 ; docName[i] != "." ; i++ )
{
    newName += docName[i];
}
newName += ext; // full png name of the file

// Create a file object to save the png
saveInFile = new File( destFolder + '/' + newName );


return saveInFile;
```

}

/*********************************************************

getPNGOptions: Function to set the PNG saving options of the 
files using the PDFSaveOptions object.

**********************************************************/

function getPNGOptions()
{

`// Create the PDFSaveOptions object to set the PDF options
var pngExportOpts = new ExportOptionsPNG24();



// Setting PNGExportOptions properties. Please see the JavaScript Reference
// for a description of these properties.
// Add more properties here if you like
pngExportOpts.antiAliasing = true;
pngExportOpts.artBoardClipping = true;
pngExportOpts.horizontalScale = 250.0;
//pngExportOpts.matte = true;
//pngExportOpts.matteColor = 0, 0, 0;
pngExportOpts.saveAsHTML = false;
pngExportOpts.transparency = false;
pngExportOpts.verticalScale = 250.0;

return pngExportOpts;`

}

Comment: Your code snippet seems to have done unspeakable horrors to markdown - you can use the <pre> codes to format them better.

Comment: I adjusted and added the source to the script. thanks for pointing it out.